# WPF Binding issue if i call the code from other UC

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Hi am having a problem to understand binding in WPF.

I have got a User Control and contains ListView, and reading data from database but it takes a minimum of 60 seconds and then fill the listview with data.
There is a status bar which shows the loading process.

If data is loaded in the memory and User opens the UC, View model loads the data to ListView. Everything works fine.

But if User opens the UC before data read finish and at the end of the reading data i call the same method in the viewModel, in the code behind data is loaded to List item but ListView is still empty. Somehow ListView doesn't show data.

```
 <ListView x:Name="ListViewUK" ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfAccountsFromExchUK}" >
```

**View Model**

```
    public class ExchequerViewModel :BaseView
{
    List<Exch_Account> exch_Accounts_UK;

    public ObservableCollection<PAMHeaderModel> ListOfAccountsFromExchUK { get; set; }



    #region CONSTRUCTOR 
    public ExchequerViewModel()
    {
       ListOfAccountsFromExchUK = new ObservableCollection<PAMHeaderModel>();
       PopulateExchequerList();
    }
    #endregion

    public void PopulateExchequerList()
    {
        exch_Accounts_UK = ExchequerMemory.ExcAccountList_UK;
        if (exch_Accounts_UK == null)
        {
            AutoClosingMessageBox.Show("Exchequer UK - datas are loading Pleae try again later.", "Information", 2000);
        }
        if (exch_Accounts_UK != null)
        {
            UmbList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (var acc in exch_Accounts_UK)
            {
                ListOfAccountsFromExchUK.Add(new PAMHeaderModel
                {
                    Company = "UK",
                    RefNo = acc.Code,
                    Name = acc.Company,
                    Subsidiary = acc.UDF6

                });

                UmbList.Add(acc.Code, acc.UDF6); ? acc.UDF6 : "";
            }
            if (ListOfAccountsFromExchUK != null)
                UKStatusInfoLabel = ListOfAccountsFromExchUK.Count();
        }
```

**User Control**

```
    public ExchequerViewModel viewModel;
    public ExchequereUC()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        viewModel = new ExchequerViewModel();
        DataContext = viewModel;
    }
```

Comment: This can't be answered without seeing the relevant code parts of the UserControl. As a hint, remove the setter (`set;`) from the `ListOfAccountsFromExchUK` property to make sure it's only set once in the view model constructor. Besides that, `exch_Accounts_UK` should not be a field of the view model class, but just a local variable in the `PopulateExchequerList()` method.

Comment: Hi Clemens. I added UC code above now but there isn't anything in the code behind. Most of the code is written in View Model. I delete set; property but still not sure why List view doesn't show Item source itmes.

Comment: As the UserControl explicitly sets its own DataContext, it is not supposed to operate on an externally supplied view model, i.e. one that is provided by the DataContext of the MainWindow?

Comment: Thank you... It makes sense.